# Write a program that returns integers corresponding to the numerals used to form the jumbled string. Integers must be sorted in ascending order

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Asked in JP Morgan:
You are given a string containing jumbled letters from several concatenated words. Each word is a numeral from zero to nine. Each numeral may be used multiple times in the jumbled string.

Write a program that returns integers corresponding to the numerals used to form the jumbled string. Integers must be sorted in ascending order.

For example, reuonnoinfe are shuffled letters of the strings one four nine. Your program's output should be 149.
Input:

A string formed from jumbled letters of numerals. For example:

reuonnoinfe

Output:

A sequence of integers used to form the string in ascending order. For example:

149

I tried solving but could not solve it. Below is my solution but it's not working. It will be great if someone can provide a solution in java.

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
   
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String line = "reuonnoinfe";
        String constNum = "zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine";
        List<String> subStringList = subString(line, line.length());
        System.out.println(calculateNumber(constNum, subStringList));
    }

    // To find all the substring from given string with length > 3 and <6
    private static List<String> subString(String str, int n) {

        List<String> retString = new ArrayList<>();
        String tempStr;
        // Pick starting point
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            // Pick ending point
            for (int j = i + 1; j <= n; j++) {
                // Print characters from current
                // starting point to current ending
                // point.
                tempStr = str.substring(i, j);
                if (null != tempStr && tempStr.length() > 2 && tempStr.length() < 4) {
                    retString.add(tempStr.toLowerCase());
                }
            }
        }
        return retString;
    }

    // find all the substring which are anagrams of one the number String.
    private static String calculateNumber(String stringConst, List<String> subStringList) {

        StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder();
        stringConst = "one";
        String[] str = stringConst.split(",");
        int cnt = 0;
        for (String obj : str) {
            for (String objSubString : subStringList) {
                if (areAnagram(obj.toCharArray(), objSubString.toCharArray())) {
                    strb.append(cnt + "");
                }
            }
            cnt++;
        }
                
        return strb.toString();
    }

    // find two string are angram
    private static boolean areAnagram(char str1[], char str2[]) {
        int NO_OF_CHARS = 256;
        // Create 2 count arrays and initialize
        // all values as 0
        int count1[] = new int[NO_OF_CHARS];
        Arrays.fill(count1, 0);
        int count2[] = new int[NO_OF_CHARS];
        Arrays.fill(count2, 0);
        int i;

        // For each character in input strings,
        // increment count in the corresponding
        // count array
        for (i = 0; i < str1.length && i < str2.length; i++) {
            count1[str1[i]]++;
            count2[str2[i]]++;
        }

        // If both strings are of different length.
        // Removing this condition will make the program
        // fail for strings like "aaca" and "aca"
        if (str1.length != str2.length)
            return false;

        // Compare count arrays
        for (i = 0; i < NO_OF_CHARS; i++)
            if (count1[i] != count2[i])
                return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: In what way is it not working ?

Comment: not able to get all combination of string

Comment: my approach is not working as for duplicate variable its falling. for example oentow should give 12 but my program gives 1122 as o is repeating twice because of which I am getting subsequence ano twice and subsequence tow also twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you know how to create array with char occurence count (`count1, count2`) - this is key for counting approach.

**Edit** the first try suffers from "breaking" combination(s) ("one" steals chars from "four + seven" etc) as Ole V.V. noticed

If we have no excessive chars, we can traverse sample array is special order: at first even indices (all these words contain unique chars like "z" in "zero"), then odd ones, and finally sort result (or generate two separate strings and merge them)

Pseudocode outline:

```
create array or list of sample strings A[0] = "zero" etc
create char count array for string "reuonnoinfe" c1
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 2)
     create char count array c2 for A[i]
     while ALL non-zero elements of c2 are <= than corresponding c1 elements:
          add  i (index!) to output
          decrement c1[] by c2[]
          // we can stop here if c1 becomes all-zero  
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i += 2)
     create char count array c2 for A[i]
     while ALL non-zero elements of c2 are <= than corresponding c1 elements:
          add  i (index!) to output
          decrement c1[] by c2[]
sort output
```

Some examples of output ([quick-made Delphi code ideone](https://ideone.com/GDL0VX)):

```
eightnineoneonefoureightsixfivesevenseven
otfoenfueeseiiivsngrenthnevhxineogeneiesv
1145677889
onethreeseven
eeetnhvreones
137
eighttwozerosixfourninesixninesevensix
evhionfxietnnnozgieeourwxrsetsiisxnesi
0246667899
twosixtwoninesevenfoureightninezerosix
onfsntweeieitsixegxtozhinnersonvrwuioe
0224667899
zerofouronefoureightninefiveseven
srnfneriouiheeeovurevtifeofngneoz
01445789
threethreefivesevenonezerofoureightfour
tunorheeierthorgvoeeuzeffnerfreeveoihts
013344578
fiveonezeroseventhreesevenfoureight
netoseeeefrieotnernorfheugevseizvvh
01345778
fiveseventwo
fnewtveeosvi
257
```

Comment: I don’t think we’re quite there yet. Say that `four` and `seven` have been jumbled some way like `sfeovuern`. So expected output is `47`. Checking for `one` all counts are non-zero, so `1` will be output. After that I don’t think we will be able to output any more digits. Checking for `four` before `one` may solve it, only then we need to sort `1` and `4` into their correct order in the final output.

Comment: @Ole V.V. Oh yes, I quickly looked for such "breaking" combinations and missed this one (perhaps others too). So problem becomes more complex  - providing "optimal covering"

Comment: four-five-eight or four-eight-eight contains enough letters for three. one-one-five can spell nine, but if checking one and/or five before nine, this won’t pose a problem. It’s not that hard to find a safe order.

Comment: For sorting the output one may again use an array of occurrence counts. Increment the corresponding position each time a digit to be output is detected. In the end iterate over the array and output each digit as many times as the count says.

Comment: @Ole V.V. Also one-five-seven:nine. But Zero, tWo, foUr,  siX and eiGht contain unque chars, so with full coverage combinations with these words are not problem, if we check them first

Comment: there can be duplicate digits in word also.

Comment: @Rishi Raj Tandon It is not a problem - if we see that `count["n"] >= 2,count["i"]>=1, count["e"] >=1`, we can compose "nine"

Comment: ok let me check